# My NSAppTransportSecurity settings in info.plist ins't working for all defined domanins and subdomains

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode7, ios9.1

in my info.plist under property NSAppTransportSecurity I added a set of domains with which my app communicates. But for some reasons my settings works only for some of added domains, not for all but I don't know why. I would be very helpful for any idea. Thanks in advance.

For example now it works for domain googleapis.com but not for imeteo.sk, imeteo.cz or any subdomain ( http://m.imeteo.cz )

Here is snippet of my info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>imeteo.cz</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>imeteo.sk</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>googleapis.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

After trying to load some of this domains or subdomains in webview I'm getting this :

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace **NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads** and **NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion** with **NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads** and **NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion** as is told in:

http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2015/06/working-with-apples-application-transport-security/

Also, I'm using **NSExceptionDomains** instead of **NSAllowExceptionDomains**.

Comment: Because I am using MoPub adverts in app, finally, I used this: <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
 <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
 <true/>
</dict>